# Visual Studio Code 2019 - Github ignores folder to commit and push

Tags: git, visual-studio

I transferred my project to my laptop via Github. However, I just noticed that one folder is not 'uploaded' on Github and there is a - (red)sign on the folder.

Any ideas on how can I fix this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Did you check your .gitignore file to see if that folder is ignored?

Comment: Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio 2019? They're **VERY** different things.